# Install Apache Zeppelin on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I have been trying to configure Apache Zeppelin on my Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS over 15 times now without success. I even reinstalled the whole OS and tried again. Initially I was trying to build it from binary files but using a custom Spark and Scala version, but although I was following all the steps in the tutorial I wasn't able to do so as the interpreters were not being configured properly.

Afterwards I tried following the readme file from here https://github.com/apache/zeppelin. and build it from source using:

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests -Pspark-2.0 -Phadoop-2.6 -Pscala-2.10 -Pyarn -Ppyspark -Psparkr -Pr
```

but when I was going to my local host the status appeared to be disconnected, so I tried again and again.

**1)** Currently I am getting a build fail error stating that

> npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.2.1

although my current version of npm is 3.5.1

Additionally I have to admit that I am a complete beginner in Linux OS, and through out the configuration process I think I:

**2)** installed a various number of java version. So as a second question how would I downgrade for the current version(openjdk version "1.8.0_91") to a lower one, how would I detect any corrupt installations/ duplicates.

**3)** on a previous unsuccessful configuration I set the zeppelin port to 8082, how can I terminate the process as I deleted the previous files before killing the process.
I already tried with `fuser 8082/tcp` or with `kill -9 <PID>` but without any success yet

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which branch are you using?

Comment: @Rockie Yang I am git cloning this https://github.com/apache/zeppelin.git

Comment: I tested yesterday with scala-2.10. It could compile, but the spark interpreter could not be started. `mvn clean package -Pspark-2.0 -Pscala-2.11 -DskipTests` works on commit 85d4df4f0c9801751abad57004760ccc10d1eb82

Comment: @Rockie Yang I run again another build. I ll see if it works

Comment: After the last build without spark. after I restart the daemon.sh file I get: Zeppelin stop                                              [  OK  ]
Zeppelin start                                             [  OK  ]
Zeppelin process died                                      [FAILED]

Comment: try to `git checkout 85d4df4f0c9801751abad57004760ccc10d1eb82` before build. Or use a version which had pass travis according to https://travis-ci.org/apache/zeppelin/builds